# Allocate memory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

We've encountered a trouble when digging into JavaScript,Please help us. Thanks in advance

Below codes, why samurai still can't call function yell

```
===>
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "Works as we would expect it to!" ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
var ninja = {}; 
assert( samurai.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "The method correctly calls itself." );
```

But in these code it can't call yell

```
===>
var ninja = { 
  yell: function(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either." ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; 
var ninja = null; 

try { 
  samurai.yell(4); 
} catch(e){ 
  assert( false, "Uh, this isn't good! Where'd ninja.yell go?" ); 
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with memory allocation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [an object null and { } behaviour in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216159/an-object-null-and-behaviour-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7):

In the first example, `yell` is a *named* function. Within the function, the symbol `yell` resolves to the function, and so it's able to call itself. So it doesn't matter that you've wiped out the `ninja` object.

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
  //             ^^^^-------------------------- the name
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  //               ^^^^------------------------ using the name
  } 
};
```

In the second example, `yell` is an *anonymous* function and it tries to call itself via `ninja.yell`, which obviously fails when `ninja` has been wiped out.

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function(n){ 
  //            ^-------------------------------------- no name
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  //               ^^^^^^^^^^-------------------------- relies on `ninja` object
  } 
};
```

---

Side note: In your first example, you wipe out the `ninja` object by assigning a different, blank object to it (`ninja = {}`), but in the second example you do it by assigning `null` (`ninja = null`). It doesn't matter, using a blank object or `null` would have the same result in both examples (although the error you receive in the second example would change).

---

Side note #2: Note that the second `var ninja = ...` line in each example is actually treated just as `ninja = ...`. The construct `var x = y;` is actually two completely unrelated things that happen at different times: The variable declaration, `var x`, which happens upon entry to the execution context (loosely, "scope") containing it; and an *assignment* operation, `x = y;`, which happens when that line of code is reached in the step-by-step execution. Having multiple declarations within a scope is a no-op. More: [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)