# an object null and { } behaviour in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

**Program1**

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "A single object isn't too bad, either." ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; //ninja.yell already assigned before ninja=null
var ninja = null; 

try { 
  samurai.yell(4); ///WHy this statement not execting??????????
} catch(e){ 
  assert( false, "Uh, this isn't good! Where'd ninja.yell go?" );
```

**Program2**

```
var ninja = { 
  yell: function yell(n){ 
    return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
  } 
}; 
assert( ninja.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "Works as we would expect it to!" ); 

var samurai = { yell: ninja.yell }; ////ninja.yell already assigned before ninja={}
var ninja = {}; //
assert( samurai.yell(4) == "hiyaaaa", "The method correctly calls itself." );//why this is working while the above code is working
```

As you can see by these two examples, which are nearly same (according to my limited knowledge), the second is executing while the first is not. I've added descriptions of my question inside comments in the above code snippets.

To the point, my question is, in Program1 `samurai.yell(4)` is not executing. However, in Program2 `samurai.yell(4)` is executing. Both are nearly the same, but why does the second execute when the first does not?

Comment: Why are you posting the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588672/allocate-memory-in-javascript)?

Comment: @thefourtheye: Oh wow, that's weird. Course material maybe? Voted to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the difference between `null` and `{}`, it depends only on how the `ninja.yell` function is defined.

The first example doesn't work because inside the `ninja.yell` function, you are referring to `ninja` again:

```
return n > 0 ? ninja.yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy";
```

So, if later on your are assigning `null` to `ninja`, this code will throw an error because `null` doesn't have a property `yell`.

---

The second example works because that's what you are exactly **not** doing. Instead of referring to the object that holds the function (`ninja`), you are giving the function a name and directly refer to that name:

```
function yell(n){ 
   return n > 0 ? yell(n-1) + "a" : "hiy"; 
}
```

The function is basically "self-contained", it doesn't depend on the values of free variables.

Comment: really good... and is there any difference b/w ninja=null and ninja={}

Comment: null is a non-assigned reference.. while {} is an empty object

Comment: @MohammadFaizankhan: See the first sentence which I just added. Of course there is a difference in general: `null` is `null` and `{}` is an object. But that's not the reason why the first example fails. It would also fail if you assigned `ninja = {}`.

Answer (score 1):

variables are references.
so in the first one, yes, ninja.yell already assigned before ninja=null, but samurai.yell is a reference to ninja.yell - it is pointing to ninja.yell.

if you then later set ninja to null, samurai.yell, which is pointing to ninja, will also be null

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. It may help you out (the title of the question is not accurate though): 
[Allocate memory in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588672/allocate-memory-in-javascript)

Comment: [You should avoid posting link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=link+only+answers)

Comment: Sorry. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: No worries, just trying to help you avoid any bad feedback from people! If you'd like to improve this answer, try to include some of the details from your link inside of this (in your own words, not just a copy and paste). A good rule of thumb is to think, "if this link ended up going nowhere, would my answer still be valuable"

Comment: But since in this case it's a link to another SO question, it should be a comment and/or vote/flag the question as duplicate. Don't duplicate answers.

Comment: There needs to be a duplicate question system here. The duplicate isn't apparent though from the question though.  I guess I could have indicated it's a duplicate even though the title isn't apparent.